# How do I make my application jump in front of everything if clicked on?

Tags: fullscreen, smalltalk

The Application I am using does not jump infront of everything if I click on it, that means I have to minimize every single window for a clear view. How can I change this?

also the application is just working in "pseudo fullscreen" how do I make it go "real" fullscreen? (I assume this could solve the first problem)

please note I am not the programmer but I am trying to solve this for the original programmer so if you could just give me some code that would be really appreciated.

Comment: On what do you click? What should jump? (application ≠ window) Why is this related to smalltalk? To which dialect?

Answer (score 2):

And Squeak can do multiple host windows since 2006 but nobody has actually done anything with the capability since then.
(Sigh. Supposed to be a reply to Travis' comment)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [squeak image](http://meeq.org/hpi/pingpong.zip).

I am not the original programmer but if you click on the logo then it becomes fullscreen and overlaps the other windows.

The source code can be found in the logo. Please post it if you find it!

Also note that Smalltalk has windows inside the window. I just mean the window of the smalltalk environment.

Comment: The only Smalltalk that has "windows inside the window" is Squeak (and its offspring). Every other Smalltalk got out of that mode 20 years ago.